# Passing setInterval and callback to a new variable

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I'm storing setInterval function in an array and trying to pass it to a new variable later on.

```
this.clock = setInterval(() => {
  this.duration = this.timer.formatTime(this.userTime)
  if (this.duration === '00:00:00') {
    clearInterval(this.clock); 
    this.timer.reset();
  }
}, 1)
```

Looking in the setInterval object `this.clock.callback` has a Closure._this object but I don't know how to access it since it is with the `<function scope>` field.

Is there a way to pass the current contents of the setInterval function to a new variable?

As in...

```
this.newClock = this.clock
```

and `this.newClock` will have the same countdown time as `this.clock`.

P.S. I'm new to posting on stackoverflow.  Any tips or recommendations for asking better questions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `setInterval` returns the interval ID for that interval. You cannot use it to get access function. What you could do is create a named function and tell `setInterval` to call that. `function blah(){..}; setInterval(blah, 1);`

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan Post that as an answer.

Comment: @Barmar: Thanks. And sorry bout that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setInterval` returns the interval ID for that interval. You cannot use it to get access function. What you could do is create a named function and tell `setInterval` to call that. And then you can call that function outside of the `setInterval` too.

```
function blah()
{
}

setInterval(blah, 1);

blah();
```